# ConfirmDialog not working programatically in primeng version 7.0.5

Tags: angular, primeng

I try to call ConfirmDialog in my .ts files, but it is not working. I do all that in primeng instructions but maybe I do something wrong. Check it please on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-confirm-dialog-primeng)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to:

- add `<p-confirmDialog>` container, in your template
- add BrowserAnimationModule in app.modules
- add “node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css” in styles section of angular.json file